# Accessing Apple Authorization Services with MacRuby

Tags: authorization, macruby, osx-leopard

I'm working on a MacRuby application that needs to make updates to config files in the /etc directory. In the command line version of the application, this prompts a password and then allows the access.

But now I'm converting the application to a GUI app and I can't figure out how to integrate authorization services into the Ruby application. The example on Apple's Developer website uses Obj-C and C. A large part of the reason I'm using MacRuby is because of how simple file access is in Ruby. I'd rather not have to convert that portion of my application to Obj-C/C. Does anyone have a good example of how to use Authorization Services with MacRuby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't look into the Authorization Services but the [Macruby Introductory Tutorial](http://www.macruby.org/documentation/tutorial.html) explains how to access plain C structs and functions in the section "Accessing Static APIs".

You might also take a look at the internals of the Address book example/wrapper because a lot of the address book functionality is plain C.

Comment: Hey, this project fell by the wayside and I forgot about the question. This seems to be the correct answer, even though I never got too far in investigating.